# Weighted moving average

Tags: variance, moving-average

I am struggling to construct an answer for question 35, part b in "Introduction to Time Series Analysis and Forecasting" 2nd edition.

My idea was that if I could find the Expected Value MtW, called m, then I could compute the Variance using the following formula:

Var(X) = E(X^2) – m^2

Any suggestions on how to complete the problem?

Thanks for all of your help!

[image: Picture of the image is here]